# How to i sign message with Keypair in rust

Tags: rust, signature, keypair

How to sign some message(like phantom signature) having a Keypair? I've seen some javascript implementations but i couldn't find any rust one.

````
const provider = getProvider(); // see "Detecting the Provider"
const message = `To avoid digital dognappers, sign below to authenticate with CryptoCorgis`;
const encodedMessage = new TextEncoder().encode(message);
const signedMessage = await provider.signMessage(encodedMessage, "utf8")```
````

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `Keypair`, you can simply call `sign_message` on the `Signer` trait, which would look like:

```
let keypair = Keypair::new();
let message = "To avoid digital dognappers, sign below to authenticate with CryptoCorgis";
let signature = keypair.sign_message(message.as_bytes());
```

You can check out the source code at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/1db7da5c32231b2ae72be29173c9ded986544f62/sdk/src/signer/keypair.rs#L93